# Lua callback into module

Tags: module, callback, lua

My script registers itself for a callback using

```
require "cmodule"
index = 1
cmodule.RegisterSoftButtonDownCallback(index, "callbackFunc")
```

where callbackFunc is the name (a string) of the callback function. Now I turned this script into a module, but the callback is not called anymore, I assume because the callback function is not in the scope of the cmodule. How can I solve this? (Lua newbie)

cmodule is a device driver that has Lua bindings.

Edit: My complete solution based in the answer from BMitch below:

```
require "cmodule"
local modname = "myModule"
local M = {}
_G[modname] = M
package.loaded[modname] = M
local cmodule = cmodule
local _G = _G
setfenv(1,M)

function callbackFunc()
    -- use module vars here
end
_G["myModule_callbackFunc"] = callbackFunc
index = 1
cmodule.RegisterSoftButtonDownCallback(index, "myModule_callbackFunc")
```

Comment: What is `cmodule`? That's not part of Lua 5.1. Where does it come from? Is it a global variable or a local one?

Comment: cmodule is a device driver that has Lua bindings. I do a require "cmodule" at the start of the script (loading cmodule.dll). It is not developed by me. If it is important to know what exactly it does I could try to contact the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have something defined in the global space for a string to be evaluated back to a function call.

Depending on how they implemented `RegisterSoftButtonDownCallback`, you may be stuck defining the function itself, rather than the table/field combination like `myModule.callbackFunc`.  To minimize the namespace pollution, if you can't use `myModule.callbackFunc`, then I'd suggest `myModule_callbackFunc=myModule.callbackFunc` or something similar.  So your code would look like:

```
require "cmodule"
index = 1
myModule_callbackFunc=myModule.callbackFunc
cmodule.RegisterSoftButtonDownCallback(index, "myModule_callbackFunc")
```

For a better fix, I would work with the cmodule developers to get their program to accept a function pointer rather than a string.  Then your code would look like:

```
require "cmodule"
index = 1
cmodule.RegisterSoftButtonDownCallback(index, myModule.callbackFunc)
```

Comment: Thanks, this set me on the right track. I will add my solution to the original question so that others can benefit from it. If you think it can be improved upon then please comment.